# Describe vs EntityDefinition for non-active features

Tags: apex, describesobject

Is this supposedly a bug? Have anyone came across this already? Asking because I was under the impression both should have the same behaviour.

I tried to use a query against [EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) instead of `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ContentNote');` but it returned result even when Content Notes is disabled, in contrast, the describe call only returns non-null if the feature is enabled.

This is the query:

```
select NamespacePrefix, QualifiedApiName, Publisher.isSalesforce
from EntityDefinition
where DeveloperName = 'ContentNote' and Publisher.isSalesforce = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, only because the documentation doesn't say that it can't return objects that are not enabled... so it's more Undefined Behavior than anything. If you're looking for fast feature detection, use Type.forName instead:

```
if(Type.forName('Schema.ContentNote') != null) {
```

This form is blazing fast, does not consume queries, and should serve all of your needs.

Comment: This is a golden nugget, thank you!

Comment: I know what you mean @sfdcfox, as usual, very useful info, was double-checking if the documentation as specific enough. As a side-note I tested `if(Type.forName('Schema', 'ContentNote') != null)` and that seems to be as good as your suggestion with a plus that uses `Schema` as a namespace and avoid collision with possible `Schema` classes un-namespaced code.

Comment: @JefersonChaves I didn't actually know that was supported. I presumed that namespace in the docs always meant a managed package namespace. That's useful to know!

Comment: Not sure if is supported, but it works with Salesforce namespace, not only managed package namespaces.